# Post method not working inspite of adding CSRF Token

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel, I was trying to use a form and thus used `post` method in it after adding CSRF Token. Also I have downloaded `form builder package` and have made all the adjustments needed for the same. But somehow, the `post` method in the `routes` is not working. Although I tried using `get` and `any` method in routes and they worked perfect fine.

`Controller`:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo "admin controller";
    }

    public function formSubmit()
    {
        echo "Form Submit Method";
        return view('layouts\formView');
    }
}
```

`View`:

```
@extends('layouts\masterLayout')
@section('head')

{!!Form::open(['route'=>'f.submit'])!!}
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
{!!Form::text('field-one')!!}
{!!Form::submit('')!!}
@endsection
```

`Route`:

```
Route::post('form-submit',['uses'=>'Admin\AdminController@formSubmit', 'as'=>'f.submit']);
```

#### Error: Stack Trace

```
in RouteCollection.php line 218
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 205
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 821
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Comment: if u r using `{!! Form::open([` csrf will auto generate so no need of `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Comment: @arun I tried using without the token, but the `post` method is not working! But `get` works fine.

Comment: whats the error tell ?

Comment: @JustL Getting an exception `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:`

Comment: the post are fine,cek your route. upload your route code please

Comment: `route` has been mentioned in the question above, plz refer.

Comment: try to use more simple route, example Route::post('action_form','YourController@YourAction');. in form, <form method="post" action="action_form">

Comment: In that case, supposedly, I will have to add CSRF Token?

Comment: of course, leave the csrf token, it must be there if you want to POST

Comment: I'll try that, but this one is working perfectly with `get` which means, route form, controller, everything is working just fine.

Comment: you already know about how to writing code in controller right ? if it yes, then everything gonna be allright, just try to wrote a simple code

Comment: if GET action is working perfectly , what you got with POST action ?

Comment: Exception, stack trace is mentioned above in the question

Comment: you have changed your route and form like i said ?

Comment: search laravel tutorial, go to laracast or kodepedia. there a lot of tutorial with more simple code

Answer (score 1):

Change

`{!!Form::open(['route'=>'f.submit'])!!}`

to

`{!!Form::open(['route'=>'f.submit', 'method' => 'POST'])!!}`

Reason is probably obvious ;-)

**EDIT**

Can you change the signature of the `formSubmit` function to this:

```
public function formSubmit(Request $request)
{
    echo "Form Submit Method";
    return view('layouts\formView');
}
```

Comment: Still getting an exception `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:`

Comment: Wait, what? Did you declare your route in the `web.php` file? And did you make sure the routes aren't cached?

Comment: @DontDownvoteMe, try `php artisan route:clear` also make sure your route allows for post requests

Comment: @Loek, I am using v5.2 and I have declared routes in `routes.php` and also cleared the `route cache`

Comment: @BagusTesa Cleared the `route cache` but still the same problem

Comment: If you change it to `{!!Form::open(['url'=>'form-submit', 'method' => 'POST'])!!}`, what happens?

Comment: It throws the same exception. Even tried `{!!Form::open(['route'=>'f.submit', 'method'=>'POST'])!!}` but still the same exception.

Comment: hmm, thats difficult, what does `route:list` gave you?

Comment: Plus, can you add a screenshot or provide the stacktrace of the exception? `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` is rather broad.

Comment: I'll post the entire stack trace in the question above, plz check!

Comment: Updated my answer. If this isn't it, I'm completely in the dark. The only thing I can think of is the namespace of your controller. But granted that a `get` works fine, that shouldn't be it.

Comment: I tried your way too but doesn't work, namespace isn't a problem cuz as you said it works perfectly with `get`. But thanks for all the help. I guess, will have to explore more.

Comment: and if you change `POST` in caps to `post`, with the new method signature?

Answer (score 0):

## Instead of

## Use as follow that will create Input field with unique token

{{csrf_token()}}

## Change Route To

Route::post('form-submit',[ 'as'=>'f.submit','uses'=>'Admin\AdminController@formSubmit' ]);

## change View Method

```
return view('layouts\formView');
```

## Like

```
return view('layouts.formView');
```

## For E.g

```
return view('YourFolderName.FileName');
```